# How to make consistent donut chart radius same

Tags: javascript, jquery, donut-chart

Following Output I am getting:

Using [Charisma Library](http://usman.it/themes/charisma/chart.html) implemented my donuts chart with following code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [];
    var opportunities_colors = new Array(); 
    opportunities_colors["New"] =  "#999999"; 
    opportunities_colors["Inprogress"] =  "#dd5600"; 
    opportunities_colors["Complete"] =  "#73a839"; 
    opportunities_colors["Terminate"] =  "#c71c22"; 
    opportunities_colors["Reopen"] =  "#c71c22";

    var opportunities_colors_option = new Array(); 
    // alert("opportunities_colors="+opportunities_colors["New"]);

    var i=0;
    $("#opportunities_dropdown_id option").each(function()
            {
            data[i] = {};               
            data[i].label =  $(this).text(); 
            opportunities_colors_option.push(opportunities_colors[$(this).text()]);
            data[i].data = $(this).val();
            i++;
            });

    //donut chart
    if ($("#opportunities_donutchart").length) {
        $.plot($("#opportunities_donutchart"), data,
            {
            // colors: ["green", "red", "blue", "orange", "cyan"],
            colors: opportunities_colors_option,

                series: {
                    pie: {
                        innerRadius: 0.5,
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Output I am getting ,

[image: Image Description]

Please help to make radius same for both charts